# JS filtering array using regexp on value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have `arr` with categories tree. Example: category `yy` is subcategory of `ww` and `ww` is subcategory of `zz`. I want to filter this array and get this output: `['aa_bb', 'aa_cc', 'zz_ww_yy']`. So I don't want `zz` and `zz_ww` becouse i have this in `zz_ww_yy`. I think that I must use filter function and maybe some regexp? hmmm and maybe foreach? What you think?

```
var arr = ['aa_bb', 'aa_cc', 'aa', 'zz', 'zz_ww','zz_ww_yy'];

var filtered = arr.filter(function(a){
    //???
})

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. (You're likely to need two passes through the array, and regex probably isn't much help here.) ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and filter the temporary result array with the given string.

Then check if the string is not a substring of the result set and push it if not.

```js
var array = ['aa_bb', 'aa_cc', 'aa', 'zz', 'zz_ww','zz_ww_yy'],
    result = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r = r.filter(b => a.indexOf(b) === -1);
        if (r.every(b => b.indexOf(a) === -1)) {
            r.push(a);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

try that on also, you could easely change the logic.

```js
var arr = ['aa_bb', 'aa_cc', 'aa', 'zz', 'zz_ww', 'zz_ww_yy'];

function shoulFilterCategory(arr, itemToTest, itemIndex) {
  var shouldFilter = false;

  arr.filter((item, index) => index !== itemIndex)
     .forEach(item => {
    if (item.startsWith(itemToTest) && itemToTest.length < item.length)         {
      shouldFilter = true;
    }
  });
  return shouldFilter;
}

var filtered = arr.filter(
  (item, index) => !shoulFilterCategory(arr, item, index)
);

console.log('filtered', filtered);
```